# Что означают символы $, {}, {0} в записи вывода строк?

Tags: c#, консоль

Что означают символы: $, {}, {0} - в подобных записях вывода строк?

```
Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {name}  Возраст: {age}");
Console.WriteLine("Выводится значение {0} ", count);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Со знаком доллара - это **[интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings)**, которая появилась в *C#6*. `$` указывает на то, что это самая строка будет той самой, куда можно подставить переменные напрямую, не заморачиваясь какой-нибудь конкатенацией или строкой составного формата (об этом ниже). То есть вместо записи:

```
Console.WriteLine("Имя: " + name + ", Возраст: " + age);
```

Можно записать

```
Console.WriteLine($"Имя: {name} Возраст: {age}");
```

где `name` и `age` - переменные со значениями, которые объявлены где-то выше в коде.

Фигурные скобки внутри нужны, чтобы отделить простые строки от действительно имен переменных. Иначе компилятор не смог бы понять где `name` является просто частью строки, а где подставляемая переменная.

---

Там где написано `{0}`, `{1}` и т.д. - это **[cтрока составного формата](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting#composite-format-string)**, где вместо  `{0}`, `{1}` и т.д. подставляются значения переменных, которые перечислены через запятую после это строки. Пример из доков:

```
string name = "Fred";
String.Format("Name = {0}, dt = {1}", name, DateTime.Now);
```

Здесь `Name =` и `, hours =` — фиксированный текст. Элементы форматирования — это "{0}" c индексом 0, который соответствует объекту `name`, и "{1}" с индексом 1, который соответствует объекту `DateTime.Now`.

Номер соответствует номеру переменной в перечислении `name, DateTime.Now`. То есть если расположить их так: `DateTime.Now, name`, то строка выше выведется так:

```
Name = 01.01.2017 10:10:00 , dt = Fred
```

вместо

```
Name = Fred , dt = 01.01.2017 10:10:00
```

Кроме того сами цифры в строке можно размещать в разные позиции, главное, чтобы они соответствовали номеру переменной в перечислении. Так, если написать

```
String.Format("{1}{0}Name =, dt = ", name, DateTime.Now);
```

то выведется:

```
01.01.2017 10:10:00FredName =, dt =
```

---

Возможностей интерполирования строк и строки составного формата конечно чуть больше, чем просто подставить переменную (например задать ширину поля или задать тут же формат даты и времени). Поэтому чуть более подробно можно почитать в документации по ссылкам выше

Comment: Только не "переменные", а "выражения" скорее

Answer (score 7):

Это [интерполированные строки](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interpolated-strings), эти записи обозначают места, где должны подставляться какие-то значения.

Знак доллара перед строкой указывает, что будет осуществляться интерполяция строк.

`{}` - плейсхолдеры, которые указывают места, в которые будет интерполироваться значение. Число внутри скобок обозначает порядковый номер аргумента. Вместо числа может быть также имя переменной.

```
Console.WriteLine("Имя: {0}  Возраст: {1}", Name, Age); // 0 - Name, 1 - Age
```

Также можно об интерполяции строк в c# почитать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/7.5.php)