# C# объединение строк из файла

Tags: c#

Имеется txt файл вида:

```
Джон Добрый день! 
Секретарь Здравствуйте! Вы по какому вопросу?
Джон Извините, я хотел бы сдать сессию пораньше, чтобы уехать домой.  
Секретарь По какой причине Вы хотите досрочно сдать сессию?
```

Нужно объединить 1 + 2
Результат:

```
Джон Добрый день!
Секретарь Здравствуйте! Вы по какому вопросу?
```

Потом 3 + 4

```
Джон Извините, я хотел бы сдать сессию пораньше, чтобы уехать домой.
Секретарь По какой причине Вы хотите досрочно сдать сессию?
```

И так до конца файла

Считываю файл так

```
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        string str = reader.ReadLine();
        stream.Close();


        Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Но дальше не знаю,что делать

Comment: Считывайте в цикле по две строки из файла, далее соединяйте их, и так пока файл не кончится. Если считалась одна строка, а после неё конец файла - так одну строку и оставляйте

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С помощью [библиотеки morelinq](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq) это можно сделать так:

```
var stringsPairs = File.ReadLines(...).Batch(2).Select(p => string.Join("\n", p));
```

Comment: О! Batch! Вот что я искал, но не знал, как называется! Попробовал - работает: `new[] {1,2,3,4,5,6}.Batch(2).Dump();`

Comment: Вот это вообще самое простое решение!

Answer (score 4):

Зачем читать по чуть-чуть, если можно одной строкой обойтись:

```
var text = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\downloads\asdf123.txt");
```

Или прочитать их же лениво, но по-прежнему одной строкой:

```
var text = File.ReadLines(@"C:\downloads\asdf123.txt");
```

Получим массив строк (ReadAllLines) или `IEnumerable<string>` (ReadLines):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И после этого соединить строки:

```
var result = string.Join(" ", text);
```

Разделитель по вкусу - хоть пробел, хоть перевод строки.

Если же у вас нужно по две объединить (посмотрел разметку вопроса, но не уверен, что правильно понял), то:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Twix(IEnumerable<string> data)
{
    var e = data.GetEnumerator();
    while (e.MoveNext())
    {
        var el1 = e.Current;
        if(e.MoveNext())
        {
            var el2 = e.Current;
            yield return $"{el1} {el2}";
        }
        else
        {
            yield return el1;
        }
    }
}
```

Запускаем:

```
var result = Twix(text);
```

На выходе:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И на закуску linq-однострочник (если будет нечётное число строк, то последняя не попадёт в результат):

```
var result = text.Where((a,i) => i % 2 == 0).Zip(text.Where((a,i) => i % 2 == 1), (a,b) => $"{a} {b}");
```

Comment: А как исправить string[] не содержит определения для Dump и не удалось найти метод расширения Dump

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников Я подобные примеры пишу в linqpad, а не открываю тяжеловесную visual studio - и .Dump() это очень метод расширения именно в linqpad'е. Можете заменить в данном случае на `foreach (var element in text) Console.WriteLine(element);`

Comment: я через нугет скачал библиотеку linqpad , спасибо!

Comment: А почему в linqpad ругается на эту строчку yield return $"{el1} {el2}"; Непредусмотренный символ "$"

Comment: @ИванЧернокнижников Потому что у вас C# ниже чем 6.0 и нет поддержки [интерполяции строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756670/213987)  - используйте `string.Format("{0} {1}", el1, el2)` взамен

Comment: Вариант, где последняя нечетная тоже попадет :) `File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\temp\sample.txt").Select((l, i) => new {l, key = i}).GroupBy(x=>x.key/2,x=>x.l).Select(x=> string.Join("|", x));`

Comment: @tym32167 Ответы в ответы. Так и знал, что можно лучше однострочник написать.

Comment: Я просто вам предложил улучшить ваш ответ. Писать отдельный ответ ради 1 строки смысла нет