# Создание запроса с использованием функции Entity Framework Like

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Вопрос вот в чем. Хочу создать API запрос поиска текста в базе данных. При использовании  SQL запроса `SELECT * FROM dbo.SlideDB WHERE TextSlide like '%TextTest%'` в Базе Данных мне находит все соответствия. На стороне Api не получается получить все соответствия с функцией Like().

```
 [HttpGet]
 [Route("/search/{searchform}")]

    public ActionResult Search(string searchform)
    {

         // Находит не все соответствия 
        var search = _context.SlideDB.Where(p => p.TextSlide == searchform);
        // Вылетает ошибка
        var search = _context.SlideDB.Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.TextSlide, "%{searchform}%"));

        return Ok(search);
    }
```

Comment: Что вы имеете ввиду под "на стороне API не получается передать запрос"? Входные данные некорректно попадают на экшн? Или запрос возвращает не то, что нужно из базы?

Comment: `_context.SlideDB.Where(p => p.TextSlide.Contains(searchform));` ?

Comment: @A K перефразировал

Comment: @tym32167 Если без вайлдкардов - то да, можно и просто через string.Contrains - но [это не принципиально](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708715/5752652), вопрос видимо не в том, что в базе не ищет.

Comment: @richardgir Лично у меня понимания не прибавилось. Пишите более развёрнутые вопросы. Если найдено всё, что нужно и в этом нет ошибки - то давайте вообще уберём это из вопроса? Вопрос в чём? В том, что на клиент пришли данные и клиентский js что-то не может найти?

Comment: А не `EF.Functions.Like(p.TextSlide, $"%{searchform}%"` вы хотели написать? Эти фигурные скобки интерполяции строк не сработают без доллара.

Comment: @A K пользователь tym32167 ответил на мой вопрос. Не додумался делать через Contains!

Comment: Разумеется, оба варианта рабочие, я давал ссылку на то, что это в принципе одинаковые конструкции. Но вы-то поняли, что не так было в вашем варианте?

Comment: @tym32167 Напишите как ответ ваш код,чтобы я мог закрыть вопрос!

Comment: @AK так у автора Like неверно написан, я просто сделал то ж самое, только проще в записи

Comment: добавил ответом

Comment: @AK я предложил другой код не потому, что ТС чего то не знает, а потому, что мой вариант немного компактней и ошибиться в нем чуть сложнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете либо поправить свой код

```
var search = _context.SlideDB.Where(p => EF.Functions.Like(p.TextSlide, $"%{searchform}%"));
```

либо использовать более короткую запись того же самого

```
var search = _context.SlideDB.Where(p => p.TextSlide.Contains(searchform));
```

Answer (score 4):

Пример вызван опечаткой или незнанием [интерполяции строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756670/213987). Надо было вот так:

```
EF.Functions.Like(p.TextSlide, $"%{searchform}%"
```

Также можно было ход конём сделать - использовать обычный string.Contains ([о разнице можно почитать здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45708715/5752652)):

```
_context.SlideDB.Where(p => p.TextSlide.Contains(searchform));
```