# Очень странное поведение OleDbDataReader

Tags: c#, sql, oledb

Всем доброго дня! 
Сразу суть вопроса - запрос в коде не отрабатывается верно - не приходят данные, проблема только с полем `WWG_NAME`, остальные варианты запросов с различными параметрами для всех других полей таблицы распознаются и способствуют возвращению корректного набора значений.

Т.е. если сформировать строку запроса и сделать запрос:

```
string wwgName= item.Name;
string queryString = @"SELECT WWG_PK, WWG_NAME, AWG_NAME " +
"FROM wwg_n_t WHERE WWG_NAME LIKE '*"+ wwgName+ "*';";
query = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
dataReader = query.ExecuteReader();
// если есть данные
if (dataReader.HasRows)
{
    //  обработка данных
}
```

То `dataReader.HasRows` будет равен `false`, что изрядно меня расстраивает, т.к. если взять эту же сформированную строку запроса (из Debug), она отлично отрабатывает в конструкторе запросов MS Access и выдает 10 записей минимум.
Еще больше расстраивает то, что этот код работал вчера, и переписывать всё "на адаптер Sqldata вместо sqldatreader", как советуют [тут](https://switch-case.ru/52197894) - нет совершенно никакого желания.

Конекшн вида:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source=" + path_to_base + ";");
```

Если вы сталкивались с такой некорректной работой  студии/OleDb и победили их, буду очень благодарен за информацию.

Comment: а у вас версия студии какая? (спрашиваю чтобы, кое что подсказать для удобства написания кода).

Comment: 15.9.7, кстати вопреки разумной логике вариант с "%" от @A K заработал =)

Comment: Только не должен был: насколько я понял у вас не sql server, а акцесс и в нём звёздочка является валидной. И может даже вас с практической части результат устраивает, но хорошо бы понимать механику произошедшего.

Comment: Хм, интересно. Сосбвенно рекомендую вам использовать следующий синтаксис: `string queryString = $@"SELECT WWG_PK, WWG_NAME, AWG_NAME 
FROM wwg_n_t WHERE WWG_NAME LIKE '%{item.Name}%';";`

Comment: Все правильно в аксе, в особенности в последних версиях широко практикуется для ридеров использование максимально приближеного к SQL синтаксиса.

Comment: @AK думаю вы можете опубликовать ответ, и он будет верным, просьба учесть мое мнение о том как объявлять запрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [документации SQL server нет никакой звёздочки в LIKE](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=aps-pdw-2016):

Пишите так:

```
LIKE '%"+ wwgName+ "%';";
```

Хм.. а [в ms access есть](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-like-b2f7ef03-9085-4ffb-9829-eef18358e931).

Также у вас проект поддерживает возможности c#6 по [интерполяции строк](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/756670/213987), так что вы можете писать в более кратком и удобном виде:

```
string queryString = $@"SELECT WWG_PK, WWG_NAME, AWG_NAME FROM wwg_n_t WHERE WWG_NAME LIKE '%{item.Name}%';";
```

Comment: Да, в access он есть, предположил что раз уж работаю с их базой, то и запросы надо делать в том же виде, к сожалению ошибочно. Кстати верашний код тогда не понятно почему работал.

Comment: Вы работаете с их базой - да, но ведь тут ещё важно "через какой провайдер вы работаете", а у вас какая-то версия OLEDB - по хорошему нужно посмотреть что умеет этот провайдер.

Comment: @AK, а можно добавить еще следующий синтаксис: `string queryString = $@"SELECT WWG_PK, WWG_NAME, AWG_NAME FROM wwg_n_t WHERE WWG_NAME LIKE '%{item.Name}%';";`?

Comment: @Monomax Можно, искал ссылку на so про интерполяцию чтобы было где почитать подробнее.

Comment: @Monomax я думаю, что мой синтаксис более чем подходит для данного вопроса на скорую руку. Как обращаться со строками я знаю =)

Comment: @Ja_Dim почему вы думаете, что лучше подходит? интернированные строки не пестрят кавычками - меньше тратится умственных усилий на просмотр и понимание.

Comment: @A K, исключительно потому что вопрос писался на скорую руку, с множеством изменений реального кода. @Monomax За информацию по поводу нового синтаксического сахара - большое спасибо, раньше приходилось обходиться String.Format  =)

Comment: @Ja_Dim да на здоровье, надеюсь вам понравится. AK, спасибо за то что учли мое мнение!

Comment: _Интерполяция, конкатенация..._ - Чума на оба ваши дома! Параметры же!