# Как получить при сложении двух типов double ответ типа double?

Tags: c#

```
using System;

namespace Slojenie {

  class Programm {

    static void Main (string[], args) {
      double d = 4.0;
      double d2 = 4.0;
     Console.Write(d + d2);
  }
 }
}
```

ответ нужно получить 8.0, а у меня получается 8. объявлял и третью переменную и в ней производил расчет, и приведение типов делал. и конвертировал Convert.ToDouble(); и ничего не помогает. может я что то упустил?

Comment: Вам нужно освоить _форматирование_ в желаемый вид. [Standard numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings), [Custom numeric format strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings)

Answer (score 2):

Оно и так дабл. Но вывести можешь так

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double d = 4.0;
        double d2 = 4.0;
        Console.Write($"{(d + d2):N1}");
    }
```

Comment: что означают символы $ и N1? и можно как то еще записать ответ?

Comment: про доллар https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/756670/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8B-0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA

Comment: N:1 - значит отображение одного знака после запятой. Иначе ты врядли запишешь т.к если в дабл будет целое число то консоль автоматически выведет его без запятой. Но ответ все равно будет дабл

Comment: понятно. спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

В качестве альтернативы попробуйте такой вариант, тоже интересный. Через задание формата для строки вывода. Там можно поиграться с этой штукой по разному.

```
double d = 4.0;
double d2 = 5.0;
Console.Write(String.Format("{0:0.0}", d+d2));
```